# Nested vectors not working with at function?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working for a header in c++ that make easier to manipulate vectors. But I am getting error while working in a rough subproject can you guys help me for it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using nest = std::vector<T>;

int main()
{
  nest<int> arr = {(1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 5, 6),
                   (7, 8, 9)};
  std::cout << arr.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Try to fix this error and please tell me the reason and how to fix it?

I'm trying to make manipulate vectors without writing it too long as
<vector<vector<vector...>...> but the program is not working without of no syntax error.

Comment: The expression `(1, 2, 3)` is just the same as plain `3`, because it's using [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). Perhaps you want a vector of [*tuples*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: And can you please [edit] your question to tell us about the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Perhaps there are other solutions? Always ask about the actual and real problem you want solve.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration does not do what you think it does:

```
template <typename T>
using nest = std::vector<T>;
```

`nest` is an alias template that is synonymous with `std::vector`, except it can only use the first template parameter (`std::vector` also has an `Allocator` template parameter). So `nest<T>` is exactly the same as `std::vector<T>`.

This is (presumably) what you want:

```
template <typename T>
using nest = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;
```

However, you also need to change your initialization. `(1, 2, 3)` is just an expression that produces `3`, because that's how the comma operator works. It is not a constructor call, because there is no type name before it. Instead, you can use curly braces like `{1, 2, 3}` to initialize a subobject.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using nest = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

int main()
{
  nest<int> arr = {{1, 2, 3},
                   {4, 5, 6},
                   {7, 8, 9}};
  std::cout << arr.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PxM9snPdb)